# My hdflv player showsThe youtube flash api was officially deprecated on january 27

Tags: php, html, youtube-api, html5-video, youtube-iframe-api

I am using HdFlvPlayer for playing videos on my website. Now If i pla youtube url in my player then it shows me this error:
The youtube flash api was officially deprecated on january 27.

I have go through references links but no solution.
Below i my code for hdflv player. i want to use this only player. Please Please Please help.

```
<div id="mediaspace" > 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var s1 = new SWFObject('<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/hdflvplayer/hdplayer.swf','player','100%','100%','9',"#333333");
        s1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
        s1.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
        s1.addParam('WMode','transparent');
        s1.addVariable('file','<?php echo $valVideo["Video_Url"]; ?>');
        s1.addVariable('preview','<?php echo $Video_Thumbnail; ?>');
        s1.addVariable('thumb','<?php echo $Video_Thumbnail_Small; ?>');
        s1.addVariable('autoplay','true');
        s1.write('mediaspace');
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

YouTube flash APIs are deprecated. Embed YouTube video with HTML5

Answer (score 0):

The following is directly from Googles documentation

> The deprecation of the [YouTube ActionScript 3.0 Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference), also known
>   as the YouTube Flash API (AS3), was announced on January 27, 2015.
>   YouTube Flash  embeds have also been deprecated. See the
>   deprecation policy for more information. Please migrate your
>   applications to the [IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), which can intelligently use whichever
>   embedded player – HTML () or Flash () – the client
>   supports.

Comment: I can play videos but got this deprecation notice. Is there any way to remove notice permanently?

Comment: No google is warning you to stop using it.   You will need to move to the new system.  Deprecated means that it is going to stop working they are shutting it down.   It is best to move to the new system before your code just one day stops working.